# find first transactions to a contract

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, json-rpc

I'd ike to know the date or block of the first transaction of an account that has more transactions than the Etherscan display limit, like this one for example: https://etherscan.io/address/0xb1690c08e213a35ed9bab7b318de14420fb57d8c

Any way to do that using geth and json rpc?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Etherscan API](https://etherscan.io/apis) which gives you ability to list all of the transactions for a specific range of blocks (you can set custom `startblock`/`endblock`)

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0xddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&page=1&offset=10&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

And then access it like:

```
 returnedObject.result[0]
```

Example of returned object (with list of tx objects):
[Example](https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&page=1&offset=10&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken)

---

*I know you wanted to get same result with geth, hope this answer will be still helpful.*

Comment: no, thats actually a good idea, I can use the API to get the block number and then use json rpc to do my stuff... thanks for the help